# Save file on server in wordpress using php

Tags: php, wordpress, file, server

i'm trying to save a file on server on a live domain  in wordpress using php , but when ever i try to give path it gives error and page goes blank 
Here is my code.

```
<?php
$address=content_url()."/pdf_files/".$current_user->display_name."".$attempttotal.".pdf";
$pdf->Output($address,'F');
?>
```

This code work fine in localhost but i give path manually instead of using content_url function.

Warning: file_put_contents(http://domainname.com/wp-content/pdf_files/sen.pdf): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/ameliadeol2015/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lifterlms/templates/quiz/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 1021
this is the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is solved by giving the server address instead of url address using this /home/content/site/folders/filename.php).